MS Word, how to manage the Headings in a document
In Word, I can press CTRL+F to go to Navigation, and then press the "Headings" tab in there to see section headings, which is quite useful. However, I noticed that not every heading was actually here, and then noticed that it related to the triangle-thingy in the image, and some things that should not be headings are in the Headings section.
So, I want this heading on some lines:

How do I add this header to some lines?, and
How do I remove this heading (triangle-thingy) from lines that I don't want it on?



The triangle-thingy is the indication that this heading can be closed and opened. If you wish us to see the difference between your two types of headers, you need to post online an example (OneDrive, Dropbox etc).

There are not two types of headers. As above, I am only interested in this one type. I either want it on a line, or want to remove it from a line, that's all really, and so far, I've not found how to do that.

I edited your post. Where you use the term "header" you meant "heading." These are very different things in Word jargon. See my page: What is the difference between headings and headers? https://addbalance.com/word/headersheadings.htm

Use the Built-in Heading Styles. Modify the formatting to what you want.
The triangle thingies are expand/collapse marks for any paragraph that is set to have an outline level other than Body Text. Any paragraph that has such an Outline level will also appear in the Navigation Pane if that level is displayed there.
Paragraphs that you do not want to show up in the Navigation Pane should have an Outline Level of Body Text.
When you display the Navigation Pane, outline levels 1-3 will be displayed. The user can modify how many levels are displayed.
Understanding and using Styles is central to using Word effectively. What you need to know is beyond what can be put in an answer here but there are resources available, some of which I am linking below.
However, the built-in Heading Styles are easily available. These are paragraph styles, all of which have an Outline level other than Body Text. All of them are set to keep on the same page as the first paragraph of any following text. They have "magic" properties in Word. You can modify them to be formatted and look the way you want. The Built-In Heading Styles show up easily in a Table of Contents. They can be used in Cross-References. See Why Use the Built-In Heading Styles by Word MVP Shauna Kelly.
Here are some resources that can help with this:

my article Headings That Do Not Show Up in the Navigation Pane
my page Outlining in Microsoft Word
my page The Importance of Styles in Word
Tips for Understanding Styles in Word by Word MVP Shauna Kelly
Managing Word Styles by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill
Microsoft Word Styles and Why You Should Use Them by Deborah Savadra - video
Consistent Headings Using Styles by Deborah Savadra - video
Navigation Pane Settings Add-In that give easier control over the appearance of the Navigation Pane (controls whether NP automatically appears with a document and its width, does not change what shows up in it)

Word is not a typewriter. Nor is it the same as any other program. When you start really trying to do things with it, it is not all that intuitive. Here is a series of short tutorials that can help you get the most out of it (and save a lot of time and frustration): Basic Concepts of Microsoft Word by Word MVP Shauna Kelly. If you regularly use Word, any time you spend reviewing those tutorials will be recovered within a week and you will be much happier in your Word use.
I am writing this with the understanding that you are using the Windows desktop application Microsoft Word. The Navigation Pane is different in the Mac desktop application. The other Microsoft programs named Word for use on different mobile platforms or online are far less capable and should really not be used to edit or create complex documents. Those are better used to view or print the documents.

These are very useful thanks. I use Word (for Windows) endlessly over the last 20 years, but it is a huge and esoteric app, and probably like most people, there are just many features that I mostly don't need/use (Word does so many). The CTRL+F > Headings side-panel is not ideal, as you have to go through Find/Navigation and then change tabs in that side-panel, but I have found this quite useful for some reference documents with lots of entries (if it wasn't for this, I might never need Headings). Thanks for these useful links, I'm working through the many tips.

You are welcome. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

You may use custom heading styles. There is a submenu for that and you can
create your own ones and inherit settings from other styles... There is a
lot of tutorials about this but it sometimes is a little bit of fiddling to
achieve any good results. You may manage them through the settings box
popping up at context menu or the expanded styles list.
If you want any type of automation, e.g. tables of contents, the best way is
to create multiple layers of indents etc. before writing in your doc. Then
you can also manipulate the font etc. in the doc itself and per right click
you're given the option to update your settings for that profile.

FOR REMOVING THE STYLE SETTING either there is the Clear formatting option.

OR, it is very much recommended to set up a default profile or manipulate the existing default profile for every text which is not formatted (which that is may be set up in the formatting profile settings, you can specify triggers, e.g. newlines, which change your profile to another one).
If you do so, you only have to select the default profile to revert from it being a header.


Please note that, whenever you want to create a header profile you should inherit your profile from the default heading profiles included. That is how it is recognized as header 1-x.
Here is a comprehensive tutorial vid
[yt direct]
For the question about what is headings and what not in the headings section,
probably there is some formatting issues. Sometimes the style was maybe not
applied correctly or sometimes it just took the next line as one too.
To know exactly what a heading will behave like, if you create a custom
profile or change the default profile (document-/file-specific) you may
specify, when the style will end (e.g. newline) and which style is the next
to come etc. There is a lot of good tutorials about this but I refrained from
linking msft's official help pages as I personally found them less helpful.
